# Understanding Kubernetes networking, pods with same ip

Tags: kubernetes

I checked the pods in the kube-system namespace and noticed that some pods share the same ip address.The pods that share the same ip address appear to be on the same node.

[image]

In the Kubernetes documenatation it said that "Evert pod gets its own ip address." (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/). I'm confused as to how same ip for some pods came about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was reported in [issue 51322](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51322) and can depend on the [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) you are using.

The issue was seen when using the basic [kubenet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#kubenet) network plugin on Linux.

Sometime, a [reset/reboot can help](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51322#issuecomment-388517154)

> I suspect nodes have been configured with overlapped podCIDRs for such cases.
>   The pod CIDR could be checked by `kubectl get node -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.podCIDR}'`

Answer (score 5):

Please check the Kubernetes manifests of the pods that have the same IP address as their node. If they have the parameter 'hostNetwork' set to be true, then this is not an issue.

Comment: For the screenshot provided in the question, a pod being configured as "hostNetwork" is the most relevant answer.
[hostNetwork](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#podspec-v1-core) has the pod use the host's network namespace, instead of a "pod network"

Comment: This is the reason for the pods having same IP address, when you describe pods, you can see hostnetwork set to true.

Answer (score 1):

**master-node after logging in using PuTTY**

[image: master-node after logging in using PuTTY]

**worker-node01 after logging in using PuTTY**

[image: worker-node01 after logging in using PuTTY]

It clearly shows a separate CIDR for weave network. So it depends on the network plug-in. And some cases will override the pod specification CIDR provided during initialization.

**After re-deploying across the new node - worker-node02**

[image: After re-deploying across the new node - worker-node02]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have checked my 2 node clusters created using kubeadm on VMs running on AWS.
In the manifest files for static Pods hostNetwork=true is set.
Pods are:

- -rw------- 1 root root 2100 Feb  4 16:48 etcd.yaml
- -rw------- 1 root root 3669 Feb  4 16:48 kube-apiserver.yaml
- -rw------- 1 root root 3346 Feb  4 16:48 kube-controller-manager.yaml
- -rw------- 1 root root 1385 Feb  4 16:48 kube-scheduler.yaml
- I have checked with weave and flannel.
- All other pods getting IP, which was set during cluster initialization by kubeadm:

**kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16**

ubuntu@master-node:~$ **kubectl get all -o wide --all-namespaces**

NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-2n2ff   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.17    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-4sghq   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.12    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-57lfp   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.14    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-77nrr   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.18    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-m7qbn   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.15    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-nsxvm   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.19    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-r5hr6   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.16    worker-node01              
default       pod/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94-whtcg   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.1.13    worker-node01              
kube-system   pod/coredns-f9fd979d6-nghhz                1/1     Running   0          63m   10.244.0.3     master-node                
kube-system   pod/coredns-f9fd979d6-pdbrx                1/1     Running   0          63m   10.244.0.2     master-node                
kube-system   pod/etcd-master-node                       1/1     Running   0          63m   172.31.8.115   master-node                
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-master-node             1/1     Running   0          63m   172.31.8.115   master-node                
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-master-node    1/1     Running   0          63m   172.31.8.115   master-node                
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-8k9s4                       1/1     Running   0          63m   172.31.8.115   master-node                
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-ln6gb                       1/1     Running   0          37m   172.31.3.75    worker-node01              
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-master-node             1/1     Running   0          63m   172.31.8.115   master-node                
kube-system   pod/weave-net-jc92w                        2/2     Running   1          24m   172.31.8.115   master-node                
kube-system   pod/weave-net-l9rg2                        2/2     Running   1          24m   172.31.3.75    worker-node01

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1            443/TCP                  63m   
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10           53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   63m   k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE   CONTAINERS        IMAGES                                                                                     SELECTOR
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   63m   kube-proxy        k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.19.16                                                             k8s-app=kube-proxy
kube-system   daemonset.apps/weave-net    2         2         2       2            2                              24m   weave,weave-npc   ghcr.io/weaveworks/launcher/weave-kube:2.8.1,ghcr.io/weaveworks/launcher/weave-npc:2.8.1   name=weave-net

NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                     SELECTOR
default       deployment.apps/my-nginx-deployment   8/8     8            8           20m   nginx        nginx                      app=my-nginx-deployment
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns               2/2     2            2           63m   coredns      k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0   k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                     SELECTOR
default       replicaset.apps/my-nginx-deployment-5976fbfd94   8         8         8       20m   nginx        nginx                      app=my-nginx-deployment,pod-template-hash=5976fbfd94
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-f9fd979d6                2         2         2       63m   coredns      k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0   k8s-app=kube-dns,pod-template-hash=f9fd979d6
ubuntu@master-node:~$

I will add another worker node and check.

Note: I was testing with a one master and 3 worker node cluster, where pods were getting IP from some other CIDR 10.38 and 10.39. I am not sure, but the way steps are followed matters. I could not fix that cluster.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).